# Expected expression error for if else statement

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, if-statement

Xcode complains about " Expected expression required"  for second `else if` statement  in my code.  Ive tried using parenthesis from code I had looked at on here but that didn't work and not sure what expression it wants now? Works fine until I add a second `else if` 
I realise this is probably basic objective C stuff but having never done an if statement for more then two items im a bit stuck

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


if ([text1 isFirstResponder])return arrStatus.count;

else


   if ([text2 isFirstResponder]);return arrStatus2.count;

   else ///<<<<< wants an expected expression here


       if ([text3 isFirstResponder]);return arrStatus2.count;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spurious semi-colons after some of the `if` statements:

```
if ([text2 isFirstResponder]);   <--- here
```

Other than that your code is poorly indented and you should stop putting statements on the same line as the `if`/`else if` lines:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ([text1 isFirstResponder])
        return arrStatus.count;
    else if ([text2 isFirstResponder])
        return arrStatus2.count;
    else if ([text3 isFirstResponder])
        return arrStatus2.count;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, thats noted for next time. Thats stopeed me throwing my mac on the floor with frustration!

Comment: @JSA986 yeah don't do that!  Waaaay too expensive to replace...

Answer (score 3):

You just have an extra semicolon on your second `if` statement.
It should be: `if ([text2 isFirstResponder]) return arrStatus2.count;`

PS. You're making the same mistake on the 3rd `if` as well... You should really consider using curly brackets even for one-liners.

Comment: Thank you for reply, +1, Re your suggestion of curly brackets is that a functional thing? Or just to make the code cleaner to read?

Comment: My suggestion is based on the fact that many times you begin with a simple if statement and later on you just want to expand it, so you add the curly brackets. Furthermore, in my opinion it helps readability when you have many statements. Apart from that no, the one-liners are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your function/method is required to return something, in this case an NSInteger. Yet there is a possible situation in your code where there is no return statement. In your last else, if the if statement is not correct, nothing will be returned.

```
if ([text1 isFirstResponder]) {
   return arrStatus.count;
} else {
   if ([text2 isFirstResponder]) {
       return arrStatus2.count;
   } else {
        if ([text3 isFirstResponder]) {
           return arrStatus2.count;
        }
        // nothing will be returned here
        // you can return nil or actual 0
        // return nil;
        // return 0;
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that has stopped another potential error +1 for you, ive returned nil and get a yellow warning: `incompatible pointer to interger conversion returning void from a function with result type NSInterger (AKA int)`

Comment: I'm assuming that this value should normally never be returned since it will always be 1 of the 3 if cases? Than I suggest just returning an NSInter with value wich will not make the program cause warnings or crash, since I dont actually understand what this code is supposed to do.